# insignificant coefficient but wrong sign

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, binary-data

Do I have to worry if the insignificant coefficient have a wrong sign? 
say for example: coeff is -0.05 with significant of 0.890.

Answer (score 2):

As usual for me, I think the key issue is not statistical significance but size and accuracy.

Since you say it has the "wrong sign" you were clearly expecting a positive coefficient.  You didn't get one.  Why not?  How big a coefficient were you expecting? Why?

How big is 0.05? (That may sound silly, but it depends on the units). If it is "small" then how surprising is a small coefficient (whether it is positive or negative)?

My favorite professor in grad school used to say "If you're not surprised, you haven't learned anything".  Well, you're at least somewhat surprised.  What can you learn?